# What is the problem when javac compiler creates a jarfile with lowercase class file names?

Tags: compiler-construction, jar, maven, javac

When I run the `javac` compiler it compiles code and creates a JAR file, but the names of the class files inside the JAR are all in lower case. However, the classes within the source files have both lower and upper case names. The result of this is that I cannot compile other projects which are dependent on this JAR.

Comment: That sounds very peculiar. Could you give some more detail on the source file names, class names, `javac` command line and content of the JAR file you are getting?

Comment: And a complete explanation of how you're creating the jar.

Comment: i have running javac compiler using maven command mvn install

source file is : BussinessException.java
classfile it created is : bussinessexception.class

Comment: What's the OS?  Filesystem?  Trying to write to a pre-FAT32 by any chance?

Comment: @DaveParillo - The generated classname seems too long to me for this to be the problem...

Comment: If you extract the `javac` command run by `mvn` and run it directly on the command line do you get the same problem?

Comment: i got the same problem, here is a similar problem in this post, it's the file system issue: http://www.coderanch.com/t/385170/java/java/javac-changes-camelCase-lower-case

Comment: if you are using a MVFS file system, say clearcases' dynamic view, you can turn on Case Preserving in Control Panel -> ClearCase -> MVFS, see this page: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_netadm_case_mvfs.htm

Comment: Try create a minimal project reproducing this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was happening in dynamic view of the clearcase.
I have unchecked uncheck "CaseInsensitive MVFS" from Clearcase control panel.
And restarted MVFS. (may need to restart system)

Comment: This was my problem too! Thank you!